# How to integrate socket.io with mootools

Tags: javascript, socket.io, mootools

I have a question about integration between mootools and socket.io on client :

Suppose :
- server application developed in node.js which have a socket.io listen

I want to define a class to manage connection with the server, client socket.io must reside inside this class.

Actually i'm able to send connection from this class but i'm not able to manage push event. How to correct this code ?

```
var Push = new Class({ 

    Implements: [Events], 
    initialize : function() {
        this.socketServer = '192.168.1.3';
        this.listeningPort = '8080';
        this.socketIoUrl = 'http://'.concat(this.socketServer,':', this.listeningPort);

        // 
        this.socketIO = io.connect(this.socketIoUrl, {
            'connect timeout' : 500,
            'reconnect' : false,
            'reconnection delay' : 0,
            'reopen delay' : 500,
            'max reconnection attempts' : 0
        });

        // Attach Socket.io events
        this.attachEvents();

        // Creating a socket.io room
        this.socketIO.emit('create', this.filterName);
    },

    // SOCKET.IO EVENTS
    attachEvents : function() {
        socketIO.on = function(e) {
            log.info('aaa');
            socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                log.error("SOCKET.IO CLIENT disconnected");
                this.fireEvent("disconnect", [ e.data, e ]);
            });

            socket.on('connect_failed', function() {
                log.error("SOCKET.IO connection failed ");
                this.fireEvent("connect_failed", [ e.data, e ]);
            });

            socket.on('message', function() {
                log.debug(e.data);
                processMessage(e.data); 
                this.fireEvent("message", [ e.data, e ]);
            });

        }.bind(this)

        return this
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it works.

Socket.io init must be defined in a specific method invoked by initialize. Direct initializatioin in nitialize does not work  :

```
initialize : function(filterName, instrumentCode, fieldList, bankName, userName) {
    var self = this;

    ....
    self.initConnection();
    self.attachEvents();
},

initConnection : function() {
    var self = this;

    self.socketIO = io.connect(this.socketIoUrl, {
        'connect timeout' : 500,
        'reconnect' : true,
        'reconnection delay' : 0,
        'reopen delay' : 500,
        'max reconnection attempts' : 0
    });

    logger.debug ('socket.io init');
},

attachEvents : function() {
    var self = this;

    // Attach Socket.io events
    //this.attachEvents();
    self.socketIO.on('disconnect', function() {
        logger.error('Client disconnected');
        self.initConnection();
        self.resendRequest();
    });

    self.socketIO.on('connect_failed', function() {
        logger.error('Connection failed');
        self.initConnection();
        self.resendRequest();
    });

    self.socketIO.on('message', function(data) {
        self.processMessage(data);
    });

    self.socketIO.emit('create', this.filterName);
},

resendRequest : function() {
    if (this.operationType == "SUBSCRIBE") {
        subscribe();
    } else {
        unsubscribe();
    }
},
```

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Another time I will pay more attention to bring much elements. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you've lost `this` context of your `Push` class instance.

To fix this problem you'll need to modify the attachEvents function like this:

```
// SOCKET.IO EVENTS
attachEvents : function() {
    var self = this; // save context to variable called "self"

    this.socketIO.on('disconnect', function() {
        log.error("SOCKET.IO CLIENT disconnected");
        self.fireEvent("disconnect", [ e.data, e ]);
    });

    this.socketIO.on('connect_failed', function() {
        log.error("SOCKET.IO connection failed ");
        self.fireEvent("connect_failed", [ e.data, e ]);
    });

    this.socketIO.on('message', function() {
        log.debug(e.data);
        processMessage(e.data); 
        self.fireEvent("message", [ e.data, e ]);
    });

    return this;
}
```

Comment: you are better off even doing `var f = this.fireEvent; ... f('message', e.data, e)` etc. to avoid lookup of property since you don't reference any other

Comment: I found another problem : io.connect( cant be invoked directly in initialize otherwise, connection is not working...

Comment: I think socket.io can be initialized any time you want. Why can't it be invoked in constructor of your `Push` class?

Comment: I don't know why, but if i move io.connect(this.socketIoUrl in other method and I invoke it everything is ok.